# Self signed certificate on Ubuntu 12.04 and Apache 2.4.9

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I am trying to install a self-signed certificate on an Apache server. First, I did

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

and got the following output:

```
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Enabling module socache_shmcb.
Enabling module ssl.
See /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz on how to configure SSL and create self-signed certificates.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
```

Then, I restarted apache2 and got the following error:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

In **ports.conf**, I have the following:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80


<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If I comment the line `Listen 443` inside `<IfModule ssl_module>`, I get no errors. However, that seems like I won't be able to listen to 443 requests.

What can I do to be able to put listen 443 and get no errors ?